# How to get values from array returned from xml iterator

Tags: curl

i'm using code for xml iterator and i got output like this

```
Array
(
    [RESPONSE] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://www.greencart.com/paynetz/epi/fts
            [param] => Array
                (
                    [0] => NBFundTransfer
                    [1] => 153837
                    [2] => AiHLuf2uZJXyyQ6ZHPR0MvqxcmzhK64ODSoomLi701Q%3D
                    [3] => 1
                )    
        )   
)
```

Now how to extract values from it for so that i want to convert it into url like this

http://www.greencart.com/paynetz/epi/fts?ttype=NBFundTransfer&tempTxnId=153837&token=AiHLuf2uZJXyyQ6ZHPR0MvqxcmzhK64ODSoomLi701Q%3D&txnStage=1

Answer (score 0):

For generation of url from above array returned through xml iterator please refer the below code

```
    $url=$a['RESPONSE']['url'].'?'.http_build_query($a['RESPONSE']['params']);
```

http_build_query is a php function which is used for generation of querystring from an array.

For documentation about http_build_query function please refer the below url
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php